# Unpickle the files using the statement: info = pickle.load(open(“filename.p”, “rb”))

Tags: python, pickle

I saved my pickle file called keys.p in my desktop. But when I try to unpickle I get the error no such file or directory found.

Comment: how would i do this?

Comment: You should check the path to keys.p. In particular, you seem to open `filename.p` and not `keys.p`. BTW, your conventions seem weird: usually, the extension is `pkl` and not `p`, while you do not close the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17985224/4986615