# Open file and with statement in Python

Tags: python

I have a function like:

```
def func(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [line.split('\t')[0] for line in f]
```

Is the "with" statement closing the file even when there is a 'sudden' function return? Can I ignore the "with" statement? i.e. is it safe and equivalent (from a memory leak perspective) to do,

```
def func(filename):
    return [line.split('\t')[0] for line in open(filename)]
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's safe. The context manager's `__exit__` is called even if you `return` while inside of the context, so the file handle is properly closed.

Here's a simple test:

```
class ContextTest(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print('Enter')

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print('Exit')

def test():
    with ContextTest() as foo:
        print('Inside')
        return
```

When you call `test()`, you get:

```
Enter
Inside
Exit
```

Comment: sorry it is not so clear to me, can I ignore the 'with' and use the second alternative?

Comment: @elyase: There's no memory leak in either example, but you aren't explicitly closing the file handle in the second one, which may lead to problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599980/python-close-file-descriptor-question

Comment: great example!  You might want to change the `... as test` to something else, it stopped me up a bit since your function name is also test.

Answer (score 0):

Guaranteeing this safety is actually the entire purpose of the `with...as...` syntax; it replaces `try`/`finally` blocks that would otherwise be fairly awkward. So yes, it's guaranteed to be safe, which is why I far prefer `with open as f` to `f = open`.

See http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm for a good explanation of why the syntax exists and how it works. Note that you can write your own classes with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to really take advantage of this syntax.

Also see the PEP for this feature: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/