# Python not closing file descriptors

Tags: python, linux

I am developing a long-running python script which makes many connections to different serial ports. The script crashes a few hours into its execution citing "Too many open files".

I have tracked the issue to the serial module where the .close() method does not seem to reduce the number of file descriptors python is using. I am checking this using `lsof | grep python | wc`. Using Debian 7.2 & Python 2.7.3

The example below slowly uses up more and more file descriptors until it hits the limit. Why is this and how can I avoid it??

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import serial                   #Used to communicate with pressure controller
import logging
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
logging.basicConfig(filename="open_files_test.log")

# Write unusual + significant events to logfile + stdout
def log( message ):
    time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    logging.warning( time + " " + message )
    print( message )

for i in range(2000):
    for n in range(1, 12):
        try:
            port_name = "/dev/tty" + str(n+20)
            com = serial.Serial(port_name,9600,serial.EIGHTBITS,serial.PARITY_NONE,serial.STOPBITS_ONE,0.0,False,False,5.0,False,None)
            com.open()
            com.flushInput()
            com.flushOutput()
            log("Opened port: " + port_name)
        except serial.SerialException:
            com = None
            log("could not open serial port: " + port_name)

        com.close()
        log("Closed port: " + port_name)
        time.sleep(1)

log("Finished Program")
```

Thanks

Comment: Call the GC after you're done with the file(s)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599980/python-close-file-descriptor-question

Comment: @BinaryThor: He does that. After the try..except thingy, there's `com.close()`.

Comment: @Shiftee, do you encounter any errors which are getting logged?

Comment: @glglgl No. My main program raises an IOError but I can't find anything in the logfiles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that extra `com.open` is causing the issue. According to the [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports) `serial.Serial` returns it open, so you don't need to open it once more. In Linux (all POSIXes as far as I know) `open` just increments the counter and close just decrements it. There is a deleted answer here by @wheaties advising using `with` which I would recommend as well:

```
with serial.Serial(port_name, 9600, ...) as com:
    com.flushInput()
    com.flushOutput()
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `finally` to ensure the port is closed.

```
try:
    ...
except serial.SerialException:
    ...
finally:
    com.close()
```

Comment: The `com.close` call is done *after* the try..except, so it is executed anyways.

Comment: @jazzpi Not on an exception other than `SerialException`... and, after `com = None`, it fails anyways.

Comment: @tim This is, in general, good style, but probably won't help here as `close()` is called anyways.

Comment: @glglgl: Yeah, but that would fail with another error than "Too many files opened".