# combining two list into third based on condition

Tags: python, string, list

This is python 3 code, 
there are 2 input files courses.txt and student.txt I am able to read the course information from courses.txt in a list and student information in another list.
Now I want to create a third list where a student of a particular semester should be registered to the course.

```
#course registration
list_courses=[]
with open("courses.txt",'r') as myfile1:
    for line in myfile1:
        list_courses.append(line.strip().split(','))


list_student=[]
with open("students.txt",'r') as myfile1:
    for line in myfile1:
        list_student.append(line.strip().split(','))

list_final=[]
for index,student in enumerate(list_student):
     semester=student[0]
     roll_number=(student[1])
     print (("semester=%s roll_number=%s")%(semester,roll_number))
     if roll_number.startswith('cs') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('cs'):
               list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]

print (list_final)
```

the files courses.txt is

```
cs101,C programming
cs102,Digital logic and design
cs103,Electrical engineering
cs231,IT networks
cs232,IT Workshop
cs233,IT programming
cs301,Compilers and automata
cs302,Operating Systems
cs303,Networks
cs401,Game Theory
cs402,Systems Programming
cs403,Automata
ec101,Digitization
ec102,Analog cicuit design
ec103,IP Telephony
ec201,Wireless Network
ec202,Microwave engineering
ec203,Antenna
ec301,Maths2
ec302,Theory of Circuits
ec303,PCB design
ec401,PLC programming
ec402,Scada
ec403,VLSI
```

the courses with numbers signify the semester of course i.e. cs101 means computer science student the first 1 in 101 means semester 1,
if it cs202 means a second semester course for cs.

The students.txt file is as follows

```
4,cs2313,Someone 
7,ec3325,Someone 
7,cs4890,Someone 
1,ec1008,Someone 
3,cs2002,Someone 
3,cs2009,Someone
```

The numbers 4,7 represent semester,second element in line represent roll number and third element represent name of student, now I want a new list in which based on semester I have added the course to student info i.e some record of following type in list3
7,ec3325,Someone ,ec301,ec302,ec303

I am not able to understand what to change in following part

```
for index,course in enumerate(list_courses):
     print(index,course[0])
     if(course[0].statswith(cs1))
```

so that list3=list.append(list2 append(courses that begin with cs1 or desired ))value)

The output is

```
['3', 'cs2009', 'someone', 'cs403', 'Automata']
```

*Instead the output should be*

```
['3', 'cs2009', 'someone', 'cs301','Compilers and automata'
'cs302','Operating Systems','cs303,'Networks']
```

Note the courses begin with cs3xx since the first entry in list is 3 (semester)

Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code just some tweaks:

```
#course registration
list_courses=[]
with open("courses.txt",'r') as myfile1:
    for line in myfile1:
        list_courses.append(line.strip().split(','))


list_student=[]
with open("students.txt",'r') as myfile1:
    for line in myfile1:
        list_student.append(line.strip().split(','))

list_final=[]
for semester, roll_num, name in list_student:
    faculty = roll_num[:2]
    temp_result = [semester, roll_num, name]
    course_lvl = faculty + semester
    for course_num, course_name in list_courses:
        if course_num.startswith(course_lvl):
           temp_result.extend([course_num, course_name])

    # omitting the students with no courses (comment if that's not what you want)
    if len(temp_result) > 3:           
        list_final.append(temp_result)

    # including students with no courses (uncomment if that's what you want)
    # list_final.append(temp_result)

print (list_final)
```

### After I understood better the OP question:

```
from math import ceil

list_final=[]
    for semester, roll_num, name in list_student:
        faculty = roll_num[:2]
        temp_result = [semester, roll_num, name]
        course_lvl = faculty + str(ceil(int(semester) / 2))
        for course_num, course_name in list_courses:
            if course_num.startswith(course_lvl):
               temp_result.extend([course_num, course_name])

        list_final.append(temp_result)

    print (list_final)
```

Comment: I tried your code on my machine however there is a list element `['7', 'cs4890', 'someone']`  here no course information could be added

Comment: is it good or bad? you didn't specify that you want to omit the students with no courses

Comment: there is no student with no course semester 7 or 8 will have course beginning with cs401 or ec401 4 is 4th year (cs and ec are dept codes) in my code I am getting final output  with above input files as mentioned in question.

Comment: I think I get you now. didn't understand you correctly before.

Comment: use my courses.txt and students.txt in original question

Comment: I am using your input. I read your question again. in the students file the first digit is the number of the semester. in the courses file the first digit (after cs\ec) is the number of the semester also. that means that this solution is OK. if you meant something else please edit your question.

Comment: I had a slightly different question originally but I am interested in understanding your logic as I am new to python. How  ` if len(temp_result) > 3:  ` this will be true for student with no course? this line is not clear to me.

Comment: I edited the answer to what I believe is what you intended.  The logic here is that I initialize `temp_result` list with 3 arguments, the student's semester, roll and name. after that I add to that list some courses stuff. so, if the `len(temp_result) > 3` means that some courses *were* added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I finally got the desired result.But any suggestions that can reduce the multiple if statements in my answer are welcome and also acceptable. So if there is a better way of doing please answer.

```
#course registration
list_courses=[]
with open("courses.txt",'r') as myfile1:
#      list_courses=myfile1.readlines()
#     list_courses=[x.strip() for x in list_courses]
    for line in myfile1:
        list_courses.append(line.strip().split(','))
#print ("Gathering course information from file: \n",list_courses)

list_student=[]
with open("students.txt",'r') as myfile1:
#      list_student=myfile1.readlines()
#      list_student=[x.strip() for x in list_student]
    for line in myfile1:
        list_student.append(line.strip().split(','))
#print("Here is student info: \n",list_student)

list_final=[]
x=[]
x=list_student
for index,student in enumerate(list_student):
   #  print(index,student[0])
     semester=student[0]
     roll_number=(student[1])
     print (("semester=%s roll_number=%s")%(semester,roll_number))
### if statements for cs students ### 
     if semester=='1' and roll_number.startswith('cs') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            print ("course = ",course[0])
            if course[0].startswith('cs1'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
             print (("semester=%s roll_number=%s")%(semester,roll_number))
             x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='2' and roll_number.startswith('cs'):
         for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('cs1'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='3' and roll_number.startswith('cs') :
         for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('cs2'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='4' and roll_number.startswith('cs') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('cs2'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='5' and roll_number.startswith('cs') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('cs3'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='6' and roll_number.startswith('cs') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('cs3'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='7' and roll_number.startswith('cs') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('cs4'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='8' and roll_number.startswith('cs') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('cs4'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
### if statements for ec students ####
     if semester=='1' and roll_number.startswith('ec') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            print ("course = ",course[0])
            if course[0].startswith('ec1'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
             print (("semester=%s roll_number=%s")%(semester,roll_number))
             x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='2' and roll_number.startswith('ec'):
         for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('ec1'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='3' and roll_number.startswith('ec') :
        print("entered here")
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('ec2'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='4' and roll_number.startswith('ec') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('ec2'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='5' and roll_number.startswith('ec') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('ec3'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='6' and roll_number.startswith('ec') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('ec3'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='7' and roll_number.startswith('ec') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('ec4'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])
     if semester=='8' and roll_number.startswith('ec') :
        for index2,course in enumerate (list_courses):
            if course[0].startswith('ec4'):
             #  list_final=list_student[index]+list_courses[index2]
               x[index].extend(list_courses[index2])

#print (list_final)
print (x)
```